# using sed to remove characters from mysql

Tags: mysql, sed

I use the following script to dump mysql database names and then remove all unwanted chars(leading trailing | and spaces).
It works in removing all of them though the sed is intended only to remove leading spaces.... why?

```
mysql -uuser -pmypass--skip-column-names -e "select schema_name from information_schema.schemata where schema_name not in ('Linking', 'information_schema');" | sed 's/^ *//'
```

Comment: seems impossible given your posted sed command that it would remove more than leading spaces. Could you have control-Ms or something in your input to the sed command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
sed 's/^ *//;s/ *$//'
```